# How do i make R show its computations (sentiment analysis)

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

When R is computing the sentiment values (package syuzhet), can I somehow get the program to show the exact computations leading up to, say a value 2?

I get that it assigns (according to our lexicon) for example +1 to the sentence-value if the word "good" shows up somewhere, and it subtracts 1 if "bad" is found. But i would like an output for each sentence reading something like this:

```
sentence [1]
The movie was very good, it had fun dialogue and great acting, but the ending was sad.
sentiment value [1]
"the" 0, "movie" 0, "was" 0, "very" 0, "good"+1 ... "fun"+1 ... "great"+1 ... "sad"-1 = 2
```

There must(?) be a command for this, but i can't for the life of me find it.

Comment: This is probably not possible to do directly with the functions supplied by `syuzhet`, but if you post a small example text and specify exactly what method(s) of sentiment analysis you are considering, we might be able to work something out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, using the example text from the [`syuzhet` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/syuzhet/vignettes/syuzhet-vignette.html).

```
library(syuzhet)

my_example_text <- "I begin this story with a neutral statement.  
  Basically this is a very silly test.  
  You are testing the Syuzhet package using short, inane sentences.  
  I am actually very happy today. 
  I have finally finished writing this package.  
  Tomorrow I will be very sad. 
  I won't have anything left to do. 
  I might get angry and decide to do something horrible.  
  I might destroy the entire package and start from scratch.  
  Then again, I might find it satisfying to have completed my first R package. 
  Honestly this use of the Fourier transformation is really quite elegant.  
  You might even say it's beautiful!"
```

Getting a sentiment value per sentence is simple to do using `sapply()`

```
sapply(get_sentences(my_example_text), get_sentiment)
# I begin this story with a neutral statement. 
#                                         0.00 
#         Basically this is a very silly test. 
#                                        -0.25 
#                                          ...
```

And getting a sentiment value per word can be done by using `get_sent_values()`

```
get_sent_values("happy")
# [1] 0.75
```

But to get an output like you describe we'll have to tinker a little

```
wordsentiments <- function(x, method="syuzhet") {
    word_l <- strsplit(tolower(x), "[^A-Za-z']+")[[1]]
    val <- sapply(word_l, get_sent_values, method)
    l <- length(word_l) + 1
    word_l[l] <- "TOTAL"
    val[l] <- sum(val)
    names(val) <- NULL
    data.frame(value=val, word=word_l, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

lapply(get_sentences(my_example_text), wordsentiments)
# [[1]]
#   value      word
# 1     0         i
# 2     0     begin
# 3     0      this
# 4     0     story
# 5     0      with
# 6     0         a
# 7     0   neutral
# 8     0 statement
# 9     0     TOTAL

# [[2]]
#   value      word
# 1  0.00 basically
# 2  0.00      this
# 3  0.00        is
# 4  0.00         a
# 5  0.00      very
# 6 -0.25     silly
# 7  0.00      test
# 8 -0.25     TOTAL

# ...
```